Dependency of Ito integral on choice of filtration
In the definition of Ito integral, there is a choice of filtration underlying the construction.
Specifically, let $ (\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space.
Let $ \{W_t\}_{t \geq 0}$ be a standard Brownian motion (BM) defined on this space.

We say that $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}_{t \geq 0}$ is a filtration for the given BM $ \{W_t\}_{t \geq 0}$ if:

$\{\mathcal{F}_t\}_{t \geq 0}$ is a filtration (i.e., nondecreasing as a sequence of sub-sigma-algebras).
Adaptivity holds, i.e., W(t) is $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable for all $t \geq 0$.
There’s independence of future increments, i.e., $W(u)-W(t)$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_t$ for all $0 \leq t < u$.

(Furthermore, often the “usual conditions” of completeness and right-continuity are assumed as well. I’m not sure how important/necessary they are, but anyhow.)

Now let $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}_{t \geq 0}$ be a filtration for the given BM $ \{W_t\}_{t \geq 0}$, and suppose $ \{X_t\}_{t \geq 0}$ is the process which we wish to integrate (i.e., the integrand).
We assume the following conditions to be fulfilled:

Adaptedness, i.e., $ \{X_t\} $ is adapted to the filtration $ \{\mathcal{F}_t\} $.
Square-Integrability: $ {E} \left[ \int_0^T X_s^2 \, ds \right] < \infty$.

In this setting, one can define ultimately (give precise mathematical meaning to) the “Ito-integral”, which is written as
$\int_0^T X_s \, dW_s$.
The Ito-integral is itself a random variable.
QUESTION: Now, what is unclear to me (and which I haven’t seen addressed in any texts, nor have I been able to find an explanation online anywhere) is: How does this depend on the choice of filtration involved?
Specifically, what if we had two filtrations  $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}_{t \geq 0}$ and $\{\mathcal{G}_t\}_{t \geq 0}$, both of which are filtrations for the given BM  $ \{W_t\}_{t \geq 0}$, and $ \{X_t\}_{t \geq 0}$ is a process which is adapted to each of these filtrations (and also it satisfies square-integrability condition), then will the resulting Ito integrals be the same, or not?

Yes, the Itō integral will be unique for two filtrations which satisfy the conditions. You can prove this by going back to the way we construct the Itō integral and doing so for each filtration, and showing they result in the same integral.

Thank you. So, whenever we write "$\int_0^T X_s , dW_s$" (assuming all conditions are met that it be properly defined), it is uniquely defined (i.e., unambiguous)? In other words, there isn't really a dependence on the choice of filtration? (Besides the filtration having to satisfy the 'necessary conditions'; see the ones I listed above.)
